# Side Menu Borders Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, custom-renderer

First I'd like to mention that I'm no professional at Xamarin.
The problem I'm currently facing occured after using a custom renderer to achieve a transparent master detail page on my xamarin.ios project, after achieving this, I noticed that I now have a grey border on the outside of my master detail page, I tried accessing it throught a couple properties, but none seem to work.

Here's the customer renderer code

```
    public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();

        var master = ViewControllers[0];
        master.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        var detail = ViewController.ChildViewControllers[1];
    }
```

Here's my xaml code used for the design of the side menu:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage
    x:Class="LoyaltyWorx.SideMenu"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
     xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
     xmlns:fftransformations="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Transformations;assembly=FFImageLoading.Transformations"
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LoyaltyWorx.MarkupExtensions; assembly=LoyalyWorx"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <ContentPage Title="Menu" BackgroundColor="Transparent">

            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Spacing="0">
                <StackLayout
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    VerticalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Black" Padding="50, 50, 50, 50" >
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage x:Name="ProfilePictureCircleImage" 
                                                    LoadingPlaceholder="profile_image_placeholder.png" 
                                                    ErrorPlaceholder="profile_image_placeholder.png" 
                                                    DownsampleToViewSize="true"
                                                    FadeAnimationEnabled="true"
                                                    HeightRequest="65"
                                                    WidthRequest="65">
                    <ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
                        <fftransformations:CircleTransformation/>
                    </ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
                         </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        Orientation="Vertical"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <Label
                            x:Name="FullNameLabel"
                            FontSize="18"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            TextColor="White"
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
        <BoxView HeightRequest="2" BackgroundColor="#D90B31"/>
               
             <ListView
                    x:Name="NavigationMenuItems"
                    ItemSelected="OnMenuItemSelected"
                    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource TileColour}"
                    RowHeight="60"
                    SeparatorVisibility="None"
                    SeparatorColor="Transparent"
                    Margin="0">

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <!--  Main design for menu items  -->

                             
                                <StackLayout
                                    Padding="20,10,0,10"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    Spacing="20"
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent">

                                  
               <local:TintedCachedImage TintColor="{StaticResource SideMenuIconColor}" 
                                        Source="{Binding Icon}" 
                                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                                        DownsampleToViewSize="true"
                                        HeightRequest="19" 
                                        WidthRequest="19"/>
                                    <Label
                                        FontSize="15"
                                        Text="{Binding Title}"
                                        TextColor="{StaticResource SideMenuTextColor}"
                                        VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>

    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage />
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Please assist.

Comment: Could you please post the full code of your custom renderer? It's not clear what you implemented.

Comment: @EltonGarciadeSantana Honestly speaking, besides the class name, namespace and using statements, thats all there really is for the custom renderer.

Comment: @EltonGarciadeSantana actually there is something else that might be of interest that I left out, but I can no longer edit the question, here's a pastebin link https://pastebin.com/tg2UY3RJ